# My dog has very reflective eyes but no night vision!

Tags: dogs, health, biology, anatomy, vision

I just adopted a dog from a local shelter and she bumps into things at night. She is 5 and very healthy. *I* am able to see, but she evidently cannot.

Her eyes are very reflective blue/green. I asked my vet to look at them and he said they were so reflective he couldn't see into them when shining a light. He told me to see a specialist.

I thought reflection helped with night vision! Is this correct?

Comment: please give some more details is only the nightvision bad or is there problems in daylight or low light too,and take your dog to the specialist and please tell us the result.

Comment: The eye specialist told me that her eyes are very dilated and the reflection I am seeing is the back of the retina, which in dogs, is yellow.

Answer (score 3):

The light reflecting cells in the dog's eye do send light to the light sensitive cells one extra time, giving the dog better night vision than we humans have.

But just as in humans, dogs can have eye problems and many of these problems can be treated by medication if they are diagnosed early; if you wait, the dog might be totally blind.

[Here is article about some of the eye problems dogs might have](https://wagwalking.com/condition/vision-problems).

So please take your dog to the specialist as soon as you possibly can to get this diagnosed and treated. It is important for your dog's future.

Comment: I will take her to a specialist and post the results. Thanks

Comment: I took my dog to an eye specialist in Los Angeles yesterday. She told me my dog has Progressive Retinal Atrophy. It is a genetic malady in some dog breeds. It is a degenerative disease which cannot be treated. It starts as night blindness (the rods in the retina atrophy) and spreads to day blindness (cones in the retina atrophy) during the course of a dogs life. Supplements help. Sadly, my dog will be blind in the future but I will be there for her.

Comment: this was realy sad to hear,i had a hope it could be treated in some way.but thank you for the update,if/when you are ready can you please update your question with this information so it possibly can help other people be aware of eye problems in dogs.